# Why was this question (about Star Trek starfield movements being literal or not) closed?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

Why was this question closed as off-topic?

> [Are those stars moving past the window when the ship is at warp?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85643/is-the-depiction-of-the-movement-of-stars-at-warp-in-star-trek-accurate?rq=1)

Seems to me it's as relevant as any scale question, and is answerable, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've amended the title to make it a little clearer what the OP is driving at.

From

> "Is the depiction of the movement of stars at warp in Star Trek
>   accurate?"

to

> "Are those stars moving past the window when the ship is at warp?".

Hopefully that should make it simpler for users to understand that the question *is* on-topic and get it reopened.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good edit, and good answer.

Answer (score 7):

It should be reopened.   The question is asking if there is an in-universe explanation for the depiction.   That is in bounds.

Comment: Yep. Open the damn thing already, I've got a great answer for it, chock-full of delicious quotes.

Comment: ...and it's reopened